# Using va_args without passing num (like printf)

Tags: c, variadic-functions

The following is the most basic example I can come up with to pass variable-length args to a function:

```
int printme(int num, ...)
{
    va_list ap;
    va_start(ap, num);
    for (int i = 0; i < num; ++i) {
        char *arg = va_arg(ap, char *);
        printf("%d. %s\n", i + 1, arg);
    }
    va_end(ap);
    return 1;
}

int main(void)
{
    printme(2, "X", "YY");
}
```

However, notice that I am passing in the length as the first argument (or as any argument). Is it possible to use these `va_` macros with something like a `printf`-ish function? For example, could I do something like this (without passing the number of args?

```
print2("Hello something %s %s", "Arg 1", "Arg 2");
print2("Hello something %s %s %s", "Arg 1", "Arg 2", "Arg 3");
```

If so, what would the function to receive that look like? And if it's not possible, how does `printf` implement it then?

Comment: I'm pretty sure `printf` uses the format string to find the `%` characters and then judges what to do based on them. For example, if there's an `s` after a `%` (meaning `%s`), it knows you're trying to print a string here, so it assumes the next variadic argument you pass is a string.

Comment: Yes of course you can. If `printf` can then so can you. Just parse the first string arg for the format specifiers. Just like your first example uses `num` you can access the string arg and parse it.

Comment: @kaylum oh right. So it just receives that, and detects the number from parsing the string to determine what the `count` is.

Comment: @carl.hiass — yup!

Comment: The specifiers describe both the total number of args and the type of each arg.

Comment: If you're wondering whether the language provides a way to ask how many args your variadic function was called with, the answer is no.  The caller has to somehow convey this information somehow in the fixed argument(s).

Comment: @kaylum I implemented a very basic version of this as an answer -- does that look ok?

Comment: @carl.hiass For completeness, the other C way to handle a variable number of arguments of the same type is using a reserved value to indicate the end of the list, for example `print3("hello", "arg 1", "arg 2", "arg 3", NULL);`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only want to pass strings, it can be done quite easily by writing a function to parse the first argument like `countargs(char*)` that I've written here. It returns the number of arguments:

```
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int printme(char* fmt, ...)
{
    va_list ap;
    int num = countargs(fmt);
    va_start(ap, num);
    for (int i=0; i < num; ++i) {
        char* arg = va_arg(ap, char*);
        printf("%d. %s\n", i+1, arg);
    }
    va_end(ap);
    return 1;
}

int countargs(char* fmt)
{
    int i, num = 0;
    if(strlen(fmt) < 2) 
    { 
        return 0;
    }
    for(i = 0; fmt[i+1] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        if (fmt[i] == '%' && fmt[i+1] == 's')
        {
            num++;
        }
    }
    return num;
}

int main(void)
{
    printme("%s%s", "Stack", "Overflow");
}
```

Comment: There is no need for the `strlen()` test, just use `for(i = 0; fmt[i] != '\0'; i++)`, if `fmt[i]` is not the null terminator, `fmt[i+1]` is accessible and the test for `%s` works as expected.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a basic example of detecting the number of arguments from a parsed string. It's not taking into account any special circumstances and doesn't do anything with actually formatting/parsing the strings, but shows a basic working program to show how the count can be parsed from a string:

```
int printmy(char * format, ...)
{
    // num args
    int num = 0;
    for(char idx=0, c; c=format[idx]; idx++) {
        // ignore escape char + double-percent
        if (c=='\\' || (c=='%' && format[idx+1]=='%'))
            idx++;
        else if (c=='%')
            num++;
    }

    // print variable args
    va_list ap;
    va_start(ap, format);   // need to give it the last argument before the "..."
    for (int i=0; i < num; ++i) {
        char* arg = va_arg(ap, char*);
        printf("%d. %s\n", i+1, arg);
    }
    va_end(ap);
    
    // return num args received
    return num;
}

int main(void)
{
    int num_args = printmy("Hello something \% \\% %% %s %s %s", "Arg 1", "Arg 2", "Arg 3");    
    printf("Num Args Parsed: %d\n", num_args);
}
```

And we get:

```
1. Arg 1
2. Arg 2
3. Arg 3
4.
Num Args Parsed: 4
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use macroprocessor to count arguments.

```
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int printme(int num, ...)
{
    va_list ap;
    va_start(ap, num);
    for (int i=0; i < num; ++i) {
        char* arg = va_arg(ap, char*);
        printf("%d. %s\n", i+1, arg);
    }
    va_end(ap);
    return 1;
}

#define TENTH(p1,p2,p3,p4,p5,p6,p7,p8,p9,p10,...) p10
#define NARGS(...) TENTH(__VA_ARGS__,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0)
#define printme(...) printme(NARGS(__VA_ARGS__), __VA_ARGS__)

int main(void)
{
    printme("X", "YY");
}
```

How it works:

Macro `TENTH` simply returns the *tenth* argument
Example:

```
TENTH(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k)
```

expands as `j`.

It can used to obtain a number of argument:

```
                               | tenth argument
                               v
TENTH("X", "XY", 9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0)
```

expand as `2` because `2` is the tenth argument of `TENTH`.

Similarly,

```
                                    | tenth argument
                                    v
TENTH("A", "B", "C", "D", 9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0)
```

expands as `4`.

Macro `NARGS` places its arguments *before* sequence `9,8,...` shifting the sequence to get the number of arguments.

I've used `printme` to avoid polluting namespace.Whenever a macro is expand is get **disabled** to avoid infinite recursion. It will not expand any further becaming a call to original `printme()`. The first argument `num` is computed with NARGS macro. All remaining arguments are passed after the `num` one.

There are still some disadvantages:

- works up to ten arguments, but this limitation can be easily lifted
- requires at least one argument (it's possible to workaround but it is complex)

Comment: wow that is so confusing to read. Could you please explain how the macro(s) work?